# Entity Framework Code First 5 Cascade Delete on many to many tables error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-5

I've this model

```
public class State
{
    public State()
    {
        this.Promotions = new List<Promotion>();
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.Stores = new List<Store>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        this.Promotions = new List<Promotion>();
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public virtual State State { get; set; } // Navigation Property
}

public class Branch
{
    public Branch()
    {
        this.Promotions = new List<Promotion>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public int StateId { get; set; } // Foreign key

    public virtual Store Store { get; set; } // Navigation Property
    public virtual State State { get; set; } // Navigation Property

    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
}

    public class Promotion
{
    public Promotion()
    {
        this.Stores = new List<Store>();
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.Productos = new List<Producto>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }

}
```

And this in my context:

```
// State
modelBuilder.Entity<State>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Promotions)
    .WithRequired(e => e.State)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<State>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Branches)
    .WithRequired(e => e.State)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<State>()
   .HasMany(e => e.Stores)
   .WithRequired(e => e.State)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

 // Store
modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
    .HasMany(b => b.Branches)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Store)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

// Many to many
modelBuilder.Entity<Store>().
  HasMany(p => p.Promotions).
  WithMany(s => s.Stores).
  Map(
   m =>
   {
       m.MapLeftKey("StoreId");
       m.MapRightKey("PromotionId");
       m.ToTable("Store_Promotion");
   });

modelBuilder.Entity<Promotion>().
 HasMany(e => e.Products).
 WithMany(p => p.Promotiones).
 Map(
  m =>
  {
      m.MapLeftKey("PromotionId");
      m.MapRightKey("ProductoId");
      m.ToTable("Promotion_Producto");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().
 HasMany(p => p.Promotiones).
 WithMany(b => b.Branches).
 Map(
  m =>
  {
      m.MapLeftKey("BranchId");
      m.MapRightKey("PromotionId");
      m.ToTable("Branch_Promotion");
  });
```

Now if I turn on more than one WillCascadeOnDelete of the State (first three in the fluent mapping) I get the error

> Test method Proj.Data.Tests.UnitTest1.TestPromotion threw exception:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Branch_dbo.Store_StoreId' on table 'Branch' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>       Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I know that, and I've read from Julie Lerman's book:

> Some databases (including SQL Server) don’t support multiple relationships that specify
>   cascade delete pointing to the same table

As it happens since the many to many relationship table has cascade delete coming from both related tables.

So, my question is: The only choice here is to turn off cascade delete on parent tables and handle the deletion on relationship table manually? Isn't there any workaround from Entity Framework 5 for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I understood the problem. It is not to have a many to many relationship, the problem is this

```
State -> Promotion -> PromotionStore
State -> Branch -> BranchPromotion
State -> Store -> StorePromotion
```

and then Store, Branch and Store have FK to State. So if I delete a State PromotionStore can be reached by 1st and 3rd possibilities.

What I ended up doing is turning off cascade delete for State and deleting the related records manually like this:

```
public override void Delete(State state)
{
   DbContext.Entry(state).Collection(x => x.Promotions).Load();
   DbContext.Entry(state).Collection(x => x.Stores).Load();
   DbContext.Entry(state).Collection(x => x.Branches).Load();

   var associatedPromotions = state.Promotions.Where(p => p.StateId == state.Id);
   associatedPromotions.ToList().ForEach(r => DbContext.Set<Promotion>().Remove(r));

   var associatedStores = state.Stores.Where(e => e.StateId == state.Id);
   associatedStores.ToList().ForEach(e => DbContext.Set<Store>().Remove(e));

   var associatedBranches = state.Branches.Where(s => s.StateId == state.Id);
   associatedBranches.ToList().ForEach(s => DbContext.Set<Branch>().Remove(s));

   base.Delete(state);
}
```

Comment: Which class the overriding Delete function belongs? Is it a custom implementation? How to make a Delete function be called automatically when an object is removed from the database?