# Error Generating Table Using Two Foreign Keys

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first

I'm trying to generate a database using EF5 Code First. This is my domain class for the `SmartCodeRights` table:

```
public class SmartCodeRight
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public long CodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual SmartCode Code { get; set; }

    public CodeRight CodeRight { get; set; }
}
```

This table is just made to facilitate a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `SmartCode`.

And this is part of the domain class for my `Code` table:

```
public class Code
{
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long? UserId{get; set;}
    public Virtual User User{get; set;}
    // ...
}
```

`CodeRight` is an `enum`.

Applying this two constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmartCodeRights] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SmartCodeRights_dbo.Users_UserId] 
FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId]) 
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmartCodeRights] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SmartCodeRights_dbo.SmartCodes_CodeId] 
FOREIGN KEY ([CodeId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[SmartCodes] ([CodeId]) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Leads to the following error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):` 
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_dbo.SmartCodeRights_dbo.SmartCodes_CodeId` on table `SmartCodeRights` may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

What am I doing wrong and what's the correct way to achieve this? Preferentially using `CodeFirst` `Data Annotations`.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400484/entity-framework-code-first-5-cascade-delete-on-many-to-many-tables-error?rq=1