# Model Building ASP.NET EntityFramework Cyclic Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these two entities:

```
public class Contact : PrimaryKey
{
    public ICollection<Order> OrdersPlaced {get;set;}
}

public class Order : PrimaryKey
{
    public Contact OrderedBy {get;set;}
    public Guid OrderedById {get;set;}
}
```

`PrimaryKey` is my key class:

```
public abstract class PrimaryKey
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

in my model builder in the context I do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
    .HasMany(c => c.OrdersPlaced)
    .WithRequired(o => o.OrderedBy)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I want to be able to delete a contact and all the orders associated be deleted! 
However, when I delete an Order I dont want to delete a contact.

What i've done throws a an error, saying the foreign key may cause cycles of deleting...

should i have done this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.OrderedBy)
    .WithMany(c => c.OrdersPlaced)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: The entities you've posted won't cause an FK-cycle error. There must be other entities in your model which are causing the problem.

Comment: It can't be, I added these 2, got the error. I replaced the first modelBuilder code with the second, ran the migration and it worked.

Comment: Well your entity classes aren't complete - they don't have keys for a start. I've just added these two classes (with the appropriate keys) to an empty model, and there were no errors.

Comment: @RichardDeeming please see the edits.

Comment: I've just tried again with the key defined in the base class, and it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, i have this in other places and it works as expected as well, just don't why its not in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to delete the orders, I merely just cycle through them and delete them before I delete the contact, my own implementation of cascade deleting!

```
// item is a contact
var orderIds = item.OrdersPlaced.Select(x => x.Id);
foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
    _repository.Delete(_repository.GetById<Order>(orderId));
_repository.Delete(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EF will support this OOTB. This answer explains how someone else did it by disabling cacsade delete and overriding Delete.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457270/626354

Comment: Out Of The Box. What I mean is that there's no simple, built-in way to do what your after.