# Creating an Entity with multiple one-to-many relationship and a DeleteBehavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EntityFramework Core version 2.2.

I have three entities: Team, Player and Notes. Each team can have a note for each player, so a player may have multiple team that took a note on him. A note can have only one team and one player.

```
public class Team
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public int TeamID {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("TeamID")]
    public Team Team {get; set;}
}
public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public int? PlayerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlayerID")]
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public int? TeamID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeamID")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In the intended behaviour, if a team or a player is removed from the database, any eventual note related to the team or the player must be removed. Moreover, typically I expect to search the note using the combination of PlayerID and the TeamID as search key.
This is the reason why I added to the OnModelCreating of the ApplicationDbContext the following instructions:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Note>()
        .HasKey(n => new { n.PlayerID, n.TeamID });
    builder.Entity<Team>()
        .HasMany(t => t.Notes)
        .WithOne(n => n.Team)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    builder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasMany(n => n.Notes)
        .WithOne(w => w.Player)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

When I ask to add the new entity and the OnModelCreating rules to the database using EntityFramework command Add-Migration, everything seems ok generating the following Up-Migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Notes",
        columns: table => new
        {
            PlayerID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            TeamID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            Text = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 512, nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Notes", x => new { x.PlayerID, x.TeamID });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Notes_Player_PlayerID",
                column: x => x.PlayerID,
                principalTable: "Player",
                principalColumn: "ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Notes_Team_TeamID",
                column: x => x.TeamID,
                principalTable: "Team",
                principalColumn: "ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Notes_TeamID",
        table: "Notes",
        column: "TeamID");
}
```

When it's time to update the database with the migration, the Update-Database generates an error with the following SqlException (translated from Italian to English):
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): FOREIGN KEY 'FK_Notes_Team_TeamID' in table 'Notes' may determine the creation of cycles or multiple propagation paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION or modify the other FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Following this StackOverflow post [Entity Framework Code First 5 Cascade Delete on many to many tables error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400484/entity-framework-code-first-5-cascade-delete-on-many-to-many-tables-error?rq=1) I understood that MsSql doesn't accept multiple OnDelete cascade constraints. I changed the code setting DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull instead (and making int? the foreign keys PlayerID and TeamID), but I wonder if there is a method to create an automatic Notes delete function using EntityFramework when a Team or a player is deleted.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the table from the Note side as well:
`builder.Entity<Note>().HasOne(n => n.Player).WithMany(p => p.Notes).OnDelete(...);` &
`builder.Entity<Note>().HasOne(n => n.Team).WithMany(t => t.Notes).OnDelete(...);` ?

Comment: This is the famous SqlServer "cycles or multiple cascade paths" problem. However, the way you've shown it, the model has neither "cycles" nor "multiple cascade paths". There must be something else causing it, for instance `Team` and `Player` having reference navigation to a common entity, for instance `public User CreatedBy { get; set; }` or something like that. Or `Team` having `public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }`. Please provide [mre].

Comment: You're right @IvanStoev, I didn't cite the fact that Team has a collection of Players inside, so I've edited the post to make it more related to the real situation. Anyway I will try to create the minimal reproducible example to let users to watch in it and suggest me a possible solution.

Comment: @MalteR: Isn't your code exactly equivalent to what I have in my code?

Comment: @LeonardoDaga I can only see you binding the relation from `Team` and `Player`, not `Note`. So no

Comment: Binding Note to Team and Player with my relation is equivalent to binding Player and Team to Note. In fact, changing the side of the bind as you proposed, I had exactly the same result, even in terms of Migration code.

Comment: In OnModelCreating, you have  

builder.Entity<Note>()
        .HasKey(n => new { n.PlayerID, n.TeamID }); 

 HasKey should be the primary key, ID.  By adding both PlayerID and TeamID to HasKey, it translates it into a composite primary key.  The foreign key attributes in the model take care of defining foreign keys.